# Update meta_value in wp_postmeta from an API response

Tags: wordpress, api

I'm making an API call using the wp_remote_get method to fetch data from an external source (not a WP site). The API call is working and i'm getting back the response i want which is just a number. Now i want to store this number (the response) as a meta_value in wp_postmeta with the following meta_key (donation_amount) and a specific post_id. The database table already exists. What i have so far is the API Call and the response. I've tried wp_update_post but maybe i am doing something wrong or maybe is not the right approach. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$url = 'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL_API'; // Not the real url

$response = wp_remote_get( $url );

if( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
    return false;
} else {
    $api_response = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ), true );
}


echo $api_response ['theNumber'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use WP `update_post_meta` function. check the below code.

```
$url = 'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL_API'; // Not the real url

$response = wp_remote_get( $url );

if( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
    return false;
} else {
    $api_response = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ), true );
}

$donation_amount = $api_response['theNumber'];
```

> replace `$post_id` with your post id.

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'donation_amount', $donation_amount );
```

Comment: did my answer help you?

Comment: thank you once again!! It works great. I was forgetting the $donation_amount = $api_response ['theNumber'];

Comment: Of course i have accepted your answer and i have upvoted maybe you can't see it because i have not earned the appropriate voting privilege. Thank you once again @Bhautik